# How to get jQuery intellisense in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to get jQuery intellisense working in Visual Studio.

I am using the latest jQuery version jquery-3.3.1.js and latest Bootstrap v4.3.1. I have tried every solution on Stack Overflow but nothing has yet worked for me.

I tried to reference `jquery-3.3.1.intellisense.js` but nothing happened. I also tried installing jQuery typed script and then adding `jsconfig.json` and referencing the jQuery typed script in it but unfortunately again nothing happened.

To be clear, I expect intellisense to work when I type `$`.

Comment: Javascript intellisense in VS is absolutely dreadful. Admittedly I haven't yet tried VS2019, but given all my previous experience I'd abandon hope of this ever working properly.

Comment: thanks but i hope someone will come up with a solution.@RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

1. Added a Scripts folder to my solution,
2. Added a file '_references.js',
3. Added my reference statements to jQuery (I should upgrade jQuery, huh) in there:

   ```
   ///<reference path="jquery-1.10.2.js" />
   ///<reference path="jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js" />
   ```
4. Closed/Re-opened my solution and presto:

[image: IntelliSense now showing jQuery usage]

Here is some back story:
https://www.madskristensen.net/blog/the-story-behind-_referencesjs/

Comment: thanks a lot, the article you referenced give me more understanding of the issue. I didn't try the solution because VS2019 solved the problem and now I can use IntelliSense for jquery, but your solution would work perfectly because that what visual studio use for IntelliSense.

Comment: why this keeps happening? Sometimes when I install some client libraries my IntelliSense stops working. Is there any log that I can check ?

Comment: I have this problem occasionally, too.  I haven't quite figured it out yet.  I usually test IntelliSenese whenever I add some new typings and back stuff out when it does not work.  I haven't yet (or looked very hard) for logging that might explain where the conflicts are coming from.

Comment: Intellisense works but syntax highlighting is not, jQuery code all plain white(

Answer (score 1):

just install this [jQuery-vsdoc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery-vsdoc/2.1.0?_src=template) from nuget and it works [image: Intellisense Working] in Visual Studio 2022 in Dot Net Core Project

Comment: Doesn't work in VS2022 17.4. No manual at all but seems this plugin just has to add a menu to add _references.js explained above. It doesn't anyway.

Comment: I got version 2.1.0 and all working good.