# No intellisense for Jquery in Visual Studio

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

Even after adding Jquery reference from Solution Explorer, there is no intellisense occurring after the dot(.) mark.

[image: BElow is my code snippet]

Comment: How have you "added jquery reference from solution explorer" ?  Sounds like you've just added it *to* the solution.  Do you have a _references.js?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319726/2181514

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704795/how-to-get-jquery-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get jQuery intellisense in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704795/how-to-get-jquery-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: What is your VS version?

Answer (score 3):

> No intellisense for Jquery in Visual Studio

Please try these steps:

**First**, make sure that you have installed [JQuery nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/) in your project.

**1)** disable third party extensions under **Extensions** menu in case some extensions cause this behavior.

**2)** close VS Instance, delete .vs hidden folder(a hidden folder which is in the same directory as the `xxx.sln`), `bin`, `obj` folder, restart your project and then test again.

**3)** add this on the top of your current page:

```
///<reference path="Scripts/jquery-3.5.0.js" />
```

**In addition**, if you still face this issue, you could try to create a new web application project and then test whether it is an issue of your current and if it works, you could migrate your old project into your new project.